# Java, order of statement?

Tags: java

I am new to Java and mostly new to coding too. I am trying a warmup question on codingBat. When I switch the statement after the first if condition the code works and I have no idea why.

This is the question:

> Given a string, return true if the string starts with "hi" and false
>   otherwise.

```
startHi("hi there") → true
startHi("hi") → true
startHi("hello hi") → false
```

Here is the code that I tried first:

```
  public boolean startHi(String str)

           {
        **String str2= str.substring(0,2);** **//gives error using parameter less than 2 characters long.** 



/*
        **//startHi("h") → false
        StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: 2 (line:3)**

*/

          if (str.length()<2)
          {
            return false;
          }


          if (str2.equals("hi"))
          {
            return true;
          }
          else
          {
            return false;
          }

        }
```

When moved however, it is correct and passes the test. No errors.

```
public boolean startHi(String str)
{


  if (str.length()<2)
  {
    return false;
  }

     **String str2= str.substring(0,2);** //now I magically work

  if (str2.equals("hi"))
  {
    return true;
  }
  else
  {
    return false;
  }

}
```

Can anyone tell me in relatively simple terms why moving that declaration below the if statement lets it work?

Comment: A guard against bad data does no good if you try to perform logic on said data before you check it.

Comment: Your comment (if indeed it is yours)  `//gives error using parameter less than 2 characters long.` says it all.  If someone feeds you a string of less than two chars and you immediately try to do `substring(0,2)` on it without checking the length first, `substring` throws `IndexOutOfBoundsException`.  But if you check the length first, you can avoid executing that `substring` under conditions that you _know_ would cause it to throw that exception. .

Answer (score 0):

Say, you have a String with only one character.

If you try `substring(0,2)`, you try to read 2 characters but there is only one. And that throws the error.

If you put the `length()<2` condition first and if there is only one character it `returns false`. The return statement immediately ends the function. The code below is not reachable. It doesn't execute. Therefore, no error.

You should check first to stop these errors.

Also there is a built in method that does that. Try `str.startsWith("Hi")`.